# Laravel 8 - Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on null

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, eloquent-relationship

I have a user model that can be a client or a provider.
What I need is to load a different relation depending on what type of user it is

If the user is a Client, I must load their relationship with my client model, and exactly the same in the case of being a provider

To do this, I first get the personal data with the person relationship (which works as expected) and then I try to load the conditional relationship as shown below

```
$users = User::with('person')->get();
$users->load('entity');
```

But in my browser, i receive this error

```
Error Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on null
```

This is the function of my relationship

```
public function entity() {

    switch($this->type) {

        case 'Client': 
            return $this->hasOne(Client::class,'id','client_id');
        break;

        case 'Provider':
            return $this->hasOne(Provider::class,'id','provider_id'); 
        break;

    }

}
```

Comment: when you are eager loading a relationship the instance that is being used is a new empty model instance so it doesn't have a `type` attribute with a value (you are not returning anything from the relationship method because `null` isn't a case here)... you can't dynamically do things like this in a relationship method if you want to eager load it ... this looks like you want a polymorphic relationship

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I already understand that, but what I'm looking for is to know if there is any way to obtain the relationship I need AFTER having loaded the collection

Comment: not with these relationships because it is only getting all the ids for everything in the collection then getting the records based on those ids, it isn't calling this relationship method on each model in the collection ... a polymorphic relationship is the only thing that would potentially allow you to do what you want (without having to spin through and do all this loading yourself for each individual model)

Comment: Always define the ```default:``` case in the ```switch```. Adding ```default``` case to your ```switch``` statement may resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because some of your users are not of type `Client` or `Provider`, therefore and because of how you defined the `entity()` relationship, it may doesn't exist for some of them.

Avoid any conditional within your relationships and consider using polymorphic relationships for this scenario since your `User` model can be related to more than 1 Model class.

You could simplify your model and database by using `entitable_id` and `entitable_type` within your `users` table and defining your relatiionship such as:

Entity.php model:

```
public function entitable()
{
     return $this->morphTo();
}
```

Users.php model:

```
public function entity()
{
    return $this->morphOne(Entity::class, 'entitable');
}
```

EDIT:
If you want to keep it this way, you can try something like mapping $users

```
$users = $users->map(function($user){
     return $user->type == 'Client' || $user->type == 'Provider' ? $user->load('entity') : $user;
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer Luciano, it seems to be a better solution to implement that type of relationship